# Google Gmail SMTP settings not allowing me to send emails with PHPMailer

Tags: php, codeigniter, smtp, gmail, phpmailer

I created an account on Gmail (becase the previous one was giving me the same problem) so that my application could send emails using google smtp server.

I'm using the PHPMailer library and asked it to show any log errors.

I always get a message similar to this. It vary a little, sometimes it is shorter and sometimes longer, depending on my configuration

```
2015-08-01 05:07:01 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO www.lavile.com 
2015-08-01 05:07:01 CLIENT -> SERVER: AUTH LOGIN 
2015-08-01 05:07:01 CLIENT -> SERVER: Y29udGF0by5sYXZpbGVAZ21haWwuY29t 
2015-08-01 05:07:01 CLIENT -> SERVER: WXlhdUgxMnM= 2015-08-01 05:07:01  SMTP ERROR: Password command failed: 534-5.7.9 Please log in with your web browser and then try again. Learn more at 534 5.7.9 https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754 b16sm3352387qga.48 - gsmtp 
2015-08-01 05:07:01 SMTP Error: Could not authenticate. 
2015-08-01 05:07:01 CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT 
2015-08-01 05:07:01 SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting string(82) "SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting"
```

This is my script

```
    $mail->Username = "myusername@gmail.com";
    $mail->Password = "mypassword";

    $mail->IsSMTP(); // enable SMTP
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 1; // debugging: 1 = errors and messages, 2 = messages only
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true; // authentication enabled
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl'; // secure transfer enabled REQUIRED for GMail
    $mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
    $mail->Port = 465; // or 587
    $mail->IsHTML(true);
    $mail->SetFrom($mail->Username, 'Contato Lavile');
    $mail->addAddress($mail->Username, "Contato Lavile");
    $mail->Subject = 'Novo contato no site Lavile';
    $mail->Body = $text;
    $mail->IsHTML(true);
    $mail->AltBody = $text;
```

Also GMAIL is sending automatic emails to myself alerting me that a new login attempt was blocked. I even changed some settings on my gmail to make it work but everything failed

Any idead? Do you know what could be happening?

Comment: could codeigniter be causing this error?!

Comment: You've based you code on an outdated example. Use [the one provided with PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/gmail.phps).

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend to actually read the error message:

> ... 534-5.7.9 Please log in with your web browser and then try again. Learn more at 534 5.7.9 https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754 b16sm3352387qga.48 - gsmtp

When reading this site you will find something about supporting client which provide only less secure methods of authorization. Your client is one of these so [follow the link](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255) to learn how to enable support for these application in gmail.

Comment: And also the link provided to the PHPMailer documentation that covers this exact issue: https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting

Comment: @shan - You just saved me too! https://accounts.google.com/b/0/DisplayUnlockCaptcha, this was my issue and the help link https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7126229, does say that but I hadn't gotten that far yet. Thanks for your answer, helped me after 30 minutes of tinkering already!

Answer (score 0):

You can send email without own smtp server:
1) get recipient mx hostname from dns
2) send email to port 25

Answer (score 0):

Not saying this is necessarily what happened to the topic opener but I had exactly this same error today. And the reason I got it was because I created a new e-mail address and you first need to log in to Gmail via the browser once before you can use smtp.

After logging in to the Gmail web client via the browser and going over the initial flow I was able to send via the smtp endpoint.

Answer (score -3):

`$mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";` should be something like:

```
$mail->Host = "mail.yourdomain.com";//replace your domain name
```

Comment: Not true - he's sending through gmail.